# Problems giving a url in a utf16 String to jsoup

Tags: utf-8, jsoup

I'm having some problems with URL's in Jsoup. I have been searching some information about it, but i dont find how to solve it.
I want to parse a html code wrote in UTF-8. I give a url to jsoup in a String, but it has the spansish char 'ñ'. Jsoup decode it to UTF-8 but it doesnt work well because it translate it to a different pair of chars. What can  i do?

EDIT:

I have solved the problem(my local problem) replacing 'ñ' with  its code in utf8( ñ = c3b1) like this. search = España -> Espa+"c3b1"a . Thx for all.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something like this and see if it works?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("blah").get();
doc.outputSettings().charset(Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
```

Edit:

I think you are saying you are building your URL using UTF-16, but Jsoup assumes the url you are feeding it is UTF-8.  So you need to convert your String from UTF-16 to UTF-8 before feeding it to Jsoup.  I played around with some code, maybe it will help you, though I'm not sure.  I'm not saying it's the answer, but maybe it will guide you down the path to an answer.

```
//I believe this code takes a UTF-8 string, creates a new UTF-16 string.  
String url = new String("http://www.google.com/search=España".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")), Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
```

You may need to switch it around for your situation.

Comment: No, it doesnt works. The problem is within the URL, because the url has a 'ñ' encoded in utf 16 and i need the URL to be encoded in utf 8 because im using a website to ask for information, and if i write in the website the ñ, it recognize it but if i make the connection with Jsoup, the website doesnt recognize the ñ like it should.

Comment: For example, imagine you want to parse a google search. If you write España on Google, it understands you. Imagine that you can modify the URL given by google and get another search(google.com/search="España")
The problem i have is that i have a url this, and i use to connect with jsoup and then parse the html. The string i pass to connect(url) method from Jsoup is encoded in utf16, and the the web doesnt understand the ñ. Finally, i get an empty search or something that doesnt match what i've asked.

Comment: You are getting the URL from some HTML on the web that is encoded in UTF-16, but you need it in UTF-8?  Can you post the URL of the site you are reading?

Comment: Im sorry about my english... 
The problem is with the URL. If i have the URL encoded in UFT16 with extrange chars like 'ñ', i cant get the correct html. But if i write ñ on the search bar on the website, it gives me correct information.

Comment: I understand it is with the URL.. where are you getting the URL?  Are you using Jsoup to pull the URL out of a webpage somewhere?

Comment: Ok, i'll try to explain better. I have code to make correct urls. Supose the url i have to make its always the same: BaseURL+search+END_URL. I ask for the search, then i make the URL and finally i connect to it using jsoup. I have the problem if i write a 'ñ' in the search. Better?

Comment: Thx. But the problem is still here, with me XD. The thing is that String in Java are always coded in UTF-16. You can get the bytes in other codification, but if you save them in a String java encodes it in UTF-16.
If Jsoup could accept byte[] like URL... 
NOTE:
There is any way to get the HTML from a url made of an array of bytes?
It could be the solution.

Comment: I have solved the problem(my local problem) replacing 'ñ' with the its code in utf8( ñ = c3b1) like this. search = España -> Espa+"c3b1"a